# IValueConverter and binding a DependencyObject

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ivalueconverter

I have a `ComboBox` that I need to do a converter on the `SelectedItem`. Problem is the `IValueConverter` needs the binding value but a Collection as well.  Configured a `DependencyObject` but it is giving me an error message of

> Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[MyClass]'.

Here is my `IValueConverter`

```
public class MyConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FoldersProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyCollection), typeof(ObservableCollection<MyClass>), typeof(MyClassModelToMyClassID), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<MyClass>()));
    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection
    {
        get { return GetValue(FoldersProperty) as ObservableCollection<MyClass>; }
        set { SetValue(FoldersProperty, value); }
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Amazing Convert code that uses MyCollection and Value
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //Amazing ConvertBack code that uses MyCollection and Value
    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling it:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:MyConverter x:Key="Converter" MyCollection="{Binding DataCollection}" />
</Page.Resources>
....
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyValue, Converter={StaticResource TaxCodeConverter}}" />
```

edit: added the full IValueConvert subtracted the Convert and ConvertBack code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like a BindingProxy, it needs to be [a Freezable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview). Also, don't pass a new observable collection to your metatadata. That's a reference type, so all instances of this converter will be initialized with the same actual collection instance.

Let me know if you run into some other issue, but I've done this and been able to bind to the dependency property.

Many would argue that a better approach would be a multibinding and a multi-value converter. I think there's value in having a strongly typed property with a descriptive name.

```
public class MyConverter : Freezable, IValueConverter
{
    /* omitted: Convert() and ConvertBack() */

    public MyConverter()
    {
        //  Initialize here if you need to
        MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new MyConverter();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyCollection), 
            typeof(ObservableCollection<MyClass>), typeof(MyConverter),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyCollection
    {
        get { return GetValue(MyCollectionProperty) as ObservableCollection<MyClass>; }
        set { SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

XAML usage will be just as you have it in your question: Bind the dependency property, and the binding will update that property of that instance of `MyConverter`, provided that your Page's DataContext has an appropriately typed property named `DataCollection`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converter:MyConverter x:Key="Converter" MyCollection="{Binding DataCollection}" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: What is the correct way to pass the observable collection?

Comment: Just the way you have it in your usage example should work, if `DataCollection` is a property of the Page's DataContext.

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid, `Converter={StaticResource TaxCodeConverter}}`, does not let me see variable `MyCollection`.  Yes, `DataCollection` is a property of the Page's DataContext.