# How to pass a binded List as parameter to a IValueConverter?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a multiple selection with CheckBoxes ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                        <CheckBox
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Converter={StaticResource checkboxConverter}}"
                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AgregarRolCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
                            <CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiSelectionConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="IsChecked" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </CheckBox.CommandParameter>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </CheckBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

The ComboBox is displaying a list of animals that I'm declaring in the ViewModel like this:

```
 public class ViewModel: ViewModelBase {
   public List < string > Animals {
    get {
     return new List < string > {
      "CAT",
      "GIRAFFE",
      "ELEPHANT",
      "DOG"
     };
    }
   }
   public List < string > SelectedAnimals {
    get {
     return new List < string > {
      "DOG",
      "CAT"
     };
    }
   }
```

What I want to do is, from a List named SelectedAnimals, if the animal is selected to show the CheckBox inside the ComboBox as checked. For this I have created a Converter named CheckBoxCheckedConverter for the IsChecked property of the CheckBox in which I want to send the converter the Current animal of that ComboBoxItem and the list of selected animals, and compare if the current animal is in the selected animals list.

I'm declaring the converter in my xaml in the UserControl.Resources like this:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:CheckBoxCheckedConverter x:Key="checkboxConverter" MyCollection="{Binding SelectedAnimals}"/>
        ...
</UserControl.Resources>
```

For receive the list of SelectedAnimals in my converter I have done the next code following this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493209/ivalueconverter-and-binding-a-dependencyobject) :

```
public class CheckBoxCheckedConverter : Freezable, IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (MyCollection.Contains(value.ToString()))
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public CheckBoxCheckedConverter()
        {
            MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }

        protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
        {
            return new CheckBoxCheckedConverter();
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MyCollection),
            typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(CheckBoxCheckedConverter),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

        public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection
        {
            get { return GetValue(MyCollectionProperty) as ObservableCollection<string>; }
            set { SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that MyCollection is coming as null in the converter and the converting is throwing me error for trying to do a .Contains() to a null object. Why is MyCollection variable in the converter coming as null? Is this method correct or is a better or simpler way to do this?

Comment: Look at the output window if a binding does not work as expected, it should show binding errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was passing a List, and in the converter I was declaring a ObservableCollection.